# Como transformar um String composta por números em uma lista de inteiros?

Tags: python, lista, conversão-de-tipo

Eu tenho uma lista com uma string:

```
a = ["1, 2, 3, 4"]
```

Quero pegar cada número dentro dessa lista, transforma-los em inteiros, e retornar o maior e o menor valor dessa lista. Já tentei fazer isso com o `FOR IN` dessa maneira:

```
def high_and_low(numbers):
    y = []
    for x in numbers:
        if(x == " " or ","):
            continue
        x = int(x)
        y.append(x)
    numbers = y
    mx = max(numbers)
    mn = min(numbers)
    return [mx, mn]

a = ["1, 2, 3, 4"]
print(hl(a))
```

Mas não funcionou, e algo muito estranho aconteceu com outra lista de strings:

```
def high_and_low(numbers):
    y = []
    for x in numbers:
        x = int(x)
        y.append(x)
    numbers = y
    mx = max(numbers)
    mn = min(numbers)
    return [mx, mn]

a = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
print(hl(a))
```

Com essa lista ai de cima, que contem quatro Strings, funcionou e não sei o porque.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A razão para isso acontecer é que `a = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]` são quatro strings (quatro chaves que cada uma contém um valor), sendo que `a[0] = "1"`, `a[1] = "2"` etc... No exemplo de cima, `a = ["1, 2, 3, 4"]` você só tem uma string (uma chave com um valor `a[0] = "1, 2, 3, 4"`).

Para fazer isso com exemplo e a lógica de o de cima você pode fazer:

```
def high_and_low(numbers):
    myNums = []
    for str in numbers: #neste caso a key (str) é uma (0, que a[0] = "1, 2, 3, 4")
        for char in str: #aqui vamos percorrer cada caracter da string ("1, 2, 3, 4")
            try:
                num = int(char)
                myNums.append(num)
            except ValueError as verr:
                pass

    mx = max(myNums)
    mn = min(myNums)
    return [mx, mn]

a = ["1, 2, 3, 4"]
print(high_and_low(a))
```

ou melhor ainda, para cobrir as hipoteses de serem 'strings numéricas' com dois ou mais algarismos, e se tiver a certeza que vai ser sempre o mesmo padrão nessas strings pode:

```
def high_and_low(numbers):
    myNums = []
    for str in numbers: #neste caso a key (str) é uma (0, que a[0] = "1, 2, 3, 4")   
        splitChars = str.split(", ") # o output é ['1', '2', '3', '4']
        for char in splitChars: #aqui vamos percorrer cada entrada da nossa nova lista, sem os ", "` , e tentar transformar em inteiro
            try:
                num = int(char)
                myNums.append(num)
            except ValueError as verr:
                pass

    mx = max(myNums)
    mn = min(myNums)
    return [mx, mn]

a = ["1, 2, 3, 4"]
print(high_and_low(a))
```

Answer (score 2):

A [resposta do Miguel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/103542/215) já explica o problema e dá uma proposta de solução, gostaria somente de propor uma solução alternativa caso sua lista possa conter números com mais de um dígito (ex.: `a = ["10, 20, 30, 40"]`).

Em primeiro lugar, você pode separar uma string em "pedaços" usando a função `split`:

```
>>> "10, 20, 30, 40".split(", ")
['10', '20', '30', '40']
```

Segundo, você pode aplicar uma função qualquer a cada elemento de uma lista através do *built-in* `map` (uma compreensão de listas também funcionaria, mas aqui o `map` me parece mais lógico):

```
>>> list(map(int, "10, 20, 30, 40".split(", ")))
[10, 20, 30, 40]
```

A chamada a `list` transforma o resultado numa lista, permitindo-o ser usado mais de uma vez. Então é só aplicar `max` e `min` a essa lista:

```
>>> x = list(map(int, "10, 20, 30, 40".split(", ")))
>>> [max(x), min(x)]
[40, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Acontece que `["1, 2, 3, 4"]` não passa de uma única string, apesar de `a` ser um vector, possui apenas um valor, que no caso é essa string `"1,2,3,4"` que actua como um valor único.

Já neste caso `["1", "2", "3", "4"]` o teu vector possui 4 índices com 4 valores, sendo eles `1`, `2`, `3` e `4`.

No primeiro caso poderias resolver isso, separando os valores dessa string um à um.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

a = ['1,2,3,4']
total = []

formato = 'numero {} é inteiro: {}'
for i in a[0].split(','):
    print formato.format(i, 'não' if i.isalnum() == 'true' else 'sim')
```

No final so terias de voltar reordenar a array removendo as vírgulas impostas pelo `split`, e calcular o **máximo** e **mínimo**

```
for x in a[0]:
    if (x == ","):
        continue
    total.append(x)     

print "Maior numero {}".format(max(total))  

print "Menor numero {}".format(min(total))
```

No segundo caso, onde separaste os valores por vírgulas ainda fora das aspas não há necessidade de usar o `split`, basta percorrer a array usando o **for in** e converter para inteiro usando o `int(i)`:

```
# converter string para inteiro

print type(i) # retorna <str>
print type(int(i)) # retorna <int>
```